# How do you write an excel file as a csv?

Tags: python, excel, csv

At work, I need to carry out this process every month, which involves downloading some files from a server, copying them into a new folder, deleting the existing files, etc, which is quite mundane. I tasked myself with writing a Python script to do this.

One step of this process is opening an Excel file and saving it as a CSV file. Is there anyway of doing this Python?

EDIT:

The main difficulty I have with this is two-fold. I know how to write a CSV file using the Python's csv library, but

1. How do I read in Excel files into Python?
2. Does the result from reading in an Excel file then writing it as a CSV file coincide with opening the file in Excel, and perform save-as CSV manually?
3. Is there a better way of doing this then the way suggested here?

I guess I really want an answer for 1. 2 I can find out myself by using something like Winmerge...

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: @CoffeeandClonazepam maybe you would like elaborate on that?

Comment: My answer is as broad as your question. That's probably why you are getting downvotes. Please provide more details like what you've tried so far, what issues you are facing etc.

Comment: @CoffeeandClonazepam has it ever occurred that I do not know what function I should look at, hence I asked the question...

Comment: Then do some research. Start looking into the tools available for working with Excel files in Python. SO isn't a code-writing or tutorial service, you need to put some work into this yourself.

Comment: @Lost1 Yes, it has. The thing is that Stack Overflow is not a request-in-code-out service.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that will do it directly. I suggest you search for a third-party Python add-on module to handle reading the Excel files. Once they're read in, you can write/save them using the built-in `csv` module.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that i have also tried to do before coming here...

Comment: Great! Then **show that**. Rather than *"Is there anyway of doing this"* you should be able to ask something more like *"I have looked into [some tool] and discovered that it can do [required function] but when I try [code example] then [unexpected thing] happens."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated the question, however, the reason I asked a more broad question is that there may be a better way of performing the task I want that does not actually involve in reading in each line of Excel, then write it out....

Comment: Point 1 you can learn through research, point 2 by doing it and finding out. 3 is unanswerable without some objective definition of "better", and should probably be covered on [codereview.se] once you have a working implementation you think could be improved. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate Excel files in Python, take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300544/how-do-you-write-an-excel-file-as-a-csv/41300775#41300775), where the use of [xlrd package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) is used. Example:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)
```

To manipulate CSV files in Python, take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767405/how-to-get-csv-reader-to-read-a-memory-file) and [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), where the library `csv`is used. Example:

```
import csv

with open('example.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: I looked at openpyxl. is xlrd a more appropriate tool?

Comment: "take a look at this question and answer," ... this link for this answer...

Comment: @Lost1 Updated the answer.

Answer (score -3):

I had to do this for a project in a course I took.

You dont need to involve Excel in the process as you can simply create a csv file and then open it in any program you like.

If you know how to write to a file as txt then you can create a csv. I am not sure if this is the most efficient way but it works.

When setting up the file, instead of something like:

```
data = [["Name", "Age", "Gender"],["Joe",13,"M"],["Jill",14,"F"]]

filename = input("What do you want to save the file as ")
filename = filename + ".txt"

file = open(filename,"w")

for i in range(len(data)):
    line = ""
    for x in range (len(data[i])):
        line += str(data[i][x])
        line += ","
    file.write(line)
    file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

simple replace the file extension from txt to csv like this:

```
filename = filename + ".csv"
```

Comment: 1. That doesn't help the OP at all if they're *starting* with an Excel file. 2. Nor is it a good way to handle CSVs in Python - why add commas manually? Just use `csv`! 3. Even if you don't use the standard library module, `for row in data: line = ','.join(row)` is neater than the manual munging, avoids the awkward indexing and doesn't leave a trailing comma.